# Umbraco: Detect country origin

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, umbraco7

I am pretty clueless about Umbraco and have a pre-existing Umbraco7/.Net project which needs to be able to detect user country of origin and redirect. I was hoping to use something along the lines of:

```
using System.Globalization;

string name = RegionInfo.CurrentRegion.DisplayName;
```

but, although the project launches to a 'Home' View, I can see no `HomeController` so am unsure where to begin.

Any pointers would be most welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it sort of working using Route hijacking:

```
public class HomePageController : Umbraco.Web.Mvc.RenderMvcController
{
    // GET: HomePage
    public override ActionResult Index(RenderModel model)
    {
        //Check country and redirect
        string country = RegionInfo.CurrentRegion.DisplayName;
        if (country == "France")
        {
            Response.Redirect("http://fr.mySite.org");
        }

        return base.Index(model);
    }
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not something Umbraco can do.. You need to lookup your users ip address and then do a redirect based on location. Use can use a service like https://freegeoip.net

I would suggest you to have a site structure like this:

- Home (Just a blank page. Do you redirect to subpage here)

  - /en
  - /de
  - /jp